# Query Multiple SQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to query values in more than one table and ensure the results are displayed correctly.

Each table has the unique product_id within, but how do I ensure the data lines up correctly? For example, product_price is queried from a different table and needs to be aligned with the correct product.

I'm new to SQL so apologies if this is an easy one.

---

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product ORDER BY product_publish DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['product_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_sku'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_in_stock'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_sales'] . "</td><td>" .  $row['product_price'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_available_date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_publish'] . "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: No sure which flavour of sql you mean, but trying looking at SQL JOIN for whichever it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a join (either INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN, depending on what should happen if a table lacks matching rows):

```
SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product 
  INNER JOIN <second product table> on jos_vm_product.product_id = <second product table>.product_id
  INNER JOIN <third product table> on jos_vm_product.product_id = <third product table>.product_id
ORDER BY jos_vm_product.product_publish DESC
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product ORDER BY product_publish DESC
```

the above query to me looks like you are only fetching from 1 table or view. In which case you are not selecting from multiple tables...

but for an example you would use a `JOIN` as @Matt.C suggested.

```
SELECT * -- select everything from P and PS you can specify (P.ID, PS.productPrice)
FROM jos_vm_product P
INNER JOIN jos_vm_productPrices PS -- join to another table.
ON P.ProductID = PS.ProductID -- join on what?
ORDER BY P.product_publish DESC
```